# PyCharm equivalent of Visual Studio $(ItemPath) for External Tools

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, pycharm, external-tools

Visual Studio 2017 has broken me, and I am defecting to PyCharm.

However we have a number of very useful external tools set up.   One of which looks like this:

Title: PEP8 Current Module
Command: (some path to Python27\python.exe
Arguments: $(SolutionDir)\dev_tools\pep8.py $(ItemPath)
Initial Directory : $(SolutionDir)

What can I put in to the Arguments in PyCharm Create Tool dialog to achieve the same thing?

Comment: PyCharm has built-in PEP8 integration, you do not need to set up any external tool for it.

Comment: This is an example which does not leak any company specific Intellectual Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyCharm equivalent to `$(ItemPath)` is the `FilePath` macro.

Comment: Awesome, this is just what I needed.    I started to explore the Insert Macro... section and it all made sense.  I hope to never have to go back to Visual Studio Python ever again!